# How can I fix the problem in my Quick Sort function?

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

Well, the task is to write quick sort on C++ only with one function and without "low" and "high" variable function arguments. It's my function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

void print_arr(const int* arr, int size) {
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void sort_quick(int* arr, int size) {
    int mid{ arr[size / 2] }, i{ 0 }, j{ size - 1 };
    while (true) {
        while (arr[i] < mid)
            i++;
        while (arr[j] > mid)
            j--;
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        else
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
    if (j > 0)
        sort_quick(arr, j); // most likely trouble is here
    if (i < size)
        sort_quick(arr + i + 1, size - i - 1); //or here
}

int main() {
    int size{ 10 };
    int * arr{ new int[size] };
    srand(unsigned(time(nullptr)));
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = rand() % 999 + 1;
    cout << "Quick Sort" << endl;
    sort_quick(arr, size);
    print_arr(arr, size);
}
```

The array is randomly assigned by numbers from 0 to 999.
The problem is that this function only work with array which size is less than 50. And I don't know how to fix it. What should I do with it?

Comment: Voting to close for [not being reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/nzMEE6) - Please create a [mcve] to show cases where it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I do think the problem is easily reproducible, actually, even with less than 50 elements.  Quick glance at the code shows that it doesn't make any progress if there is a  subsequence of identical values: neither `i` nor `j` changes in that case . It is actually an interesting observation that quick sort can be implemented using `std::partition()` which only uses a unary predicate to decide which objects need to be swapped (implying that the comparisons for the first and second subrange are actually not symmetric). Based on that I think the algorithm can be fixed quite easily.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I don't doubt that it's easily reproducible so OP shouldn't have a problem creating a [mcve].

OP: I see some edits to the question now, but using random numbers isn't good. At least use a fixed seed so the result is predictable.

Comment: Here's a [reproducible example](https://godbolt.org/z/cWrsW7)  with an array of 3 elements with some debug prints. It should make it easier to find the bug.